# when i pull out primary keys from my data-base they come out bracketed and i cant use them later in my code

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
import mysql.connector
config = {
    'user': 'root',
    'password': '*******',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'database': 'mydb',
    'raise_on_warnings': True
  }
pupilids=("SELECT idpupil FROM pupil Where Hm_idhm = 'GJM'")
cursor.execute(pupilids)
v=cursor.fetchall() 
v=str(v)
```

this is a part of my code from a much larger prodject but in essence i need to take this list of values that come when i executed this and put it into another query one by one. 
list:

```
[(1525,), (1565,), (1588,)]
```

but when i put it into the query

```
global pupilids
    global B
    print(pupilids[0])
    Pupil_name = ("SELECT Name, house, hm_idhm from Pupil Where idpupil ='"+str(pupilids[0])+"'")
    cursor.execute(Pupil_name)
    v=cursor.fetchall()
    print(v)
    showinfo("Window", v )
```

nothing comes up because of the brackets in the list. is there any way i could fix this or am i screwed. any help would be greatly apriciated and if you need any more info i can supply

for refrence when i run it in a sql shell it produces this:

```
+---------+
| idpupil |
+---------+
|    1525 |
|    1565 |
|    1588 |
+---------+
```

Comment: If you run your query `SELECT idpupil FROM pupil Where Hm_idhm = 'GJM'` on a standalone MySQL client program rather than from inside python, what do you get? Please [edit] your question to tell us.

Comment: sorry took me while to figure out how to do

Comment: What do you see if you print the `Pupil_name` text string containing your query? You want it to say `SELECT Name, house, hm_idhm from Pupil Where idpupil ='1525'`, I believe. But it should actually say  `SELECT Name, house, hm_idhm from Pupil Where idpupil =1525` because you don't need `'` quotes around numbers.

Comment: I actually figured it out in a similar way I just added one more variable and it was fine I just need to specify when I’m using the list but thank you for the help